# Installing single pole dimmer switch

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a single pole dimmer switch but there are 4 wires coming out of the box. I installed this as if it were a 3 way and the dimmer was humming. Any advice? [image]

Comment: Roll it back to how it was before, test it to make sure it works... then take a picture of *that*.  Not helpful to see it configured wrong, or to not mention the model number of the new dimmer or whether it *actually is* a 3-way circuit.  This kind of "Freestyling" is a bad plan where AC electrical power is concerned... I know you are seeking a combination that works, but many will "work" *and then will kill you*.  So "it works" is not a viable test of success.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: Turn the breaker off and then remove this dimmer. Then figure out what these wires are, i.e., hot, switched hot, neutral, . . . Then read and follow the instructions for this dimmer.

Comment: Make sure your common is on the black screw I use black for common then Red & White for travelers, I hope you took a photo of the original connections. But as both Jim and Harper have mentioned get it working with the original switch. Make sure both switches work with the other switch in both positions. Then you will know the common is correct.